# Labelling only with the first letter of string in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, string

I have a field called `"Genus"` where there are string values, for example, the word *'Pinus'*.

I want my label to show only the first letter of this word so in my example *'P'*.

I was trying to use Function Editor. I was contriving with `field.row[0]`, but I'm not sure with the rest of the syntax.

Maybe there is another solution for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this in your label composer, it should do the trick :

```
left("Genus", 1)
```

Here's a [list of functions](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html) you can use in your expressions

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to use the [`substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#substr) function:

```
substr("FieldName", 1, 1)
```

[image]

Replace `"FieldName"` with the name of your field.

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution employs the [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#regexp-substr) function:

```
regexp_substr("data", '^[[:alpha:]]|[0-9]')
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

There is also a solution that uses the [`array_to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-to-string) function.

```
string_to_array("test", '')[1]
```

*Note:* here I am referring to the fist character via `[1]` and not `[0]` (because it is a space even though initially there is no space in the string).

[image: result]